# Do I always have to initialize a function pointer when declaring it?

Tags: c++

Lets consider the next piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

void print()
{
   std::cout << "I feel void" << std::endl;
}

void (*func)();
func = print;
```

This does not compile, since "func does not name a type".
But I already declared about `func`'s type. It's a function pointer that takes no arguments and returns void. Why do I need to name a type again?

Comment: You can't use assignment statements like `func = print` outside of a function. However, `void (*func)() = print;` is *not* an assignment (despite appearances) - it's an *initialization*, which is part of the declaration.

Comment: `void (*func)(); int main() { func = print; }` works fine ([demo](https://ideone.com/Ar8Sc2))

Comment: Same situation: `int x; x = 1; int main() {}`.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I always have to initialize a function pointer when declaring it?

No.

However, you cannot have expression statements such as assignments in namespace scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in main! , you cant do that in namespaces:

```cpp
void (*func)();
void print()
{
    std::cout << "I feel void" << std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    func = print;
    return 0;
}
```

but if you want do that before main execution , you can try below code(I prefer dont use this , but it's helpful sometimes):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void (*func)();
void print()
{
    std::cout << "I feel void" << std::endl;
}
class Initilizer
{
public:
    Initilizer()
    {
        init();
    }
    static void init()
    {
        func = ::print;
    }
};

Initilizer obj;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    func(); /*Test func*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you switch to `std::function`? The question is about function pointers and the OP clearly seems confused by their syntax.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's function pointer too :| no difrence , I just used my default coding  -_- , 
change "void (*func)();" instead "std::function<void()> func;".